# COUNTIF in a matrix using different date formats

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I am working on an excel sample data (Sheet 1) that is related to flight bookings. The columns I am interested in are the booking and check-in date. I have created on a separate sheet (Sheet 2) a matrix with dates grouped by month and year (mmm-yy). y-axis corresponds to the booking date whereas x-axis corresponds to the check-in date.

Using this matrix I tried to count the number of bookings that each month generated for the following ones. The problem I have with COUNTIFS is that I can't integrate into the code the conversion of Sheet 1 dates from dd-mm-yy to mmm-yy in order to count the bookings in the matrix

Any ideas?

Do you believe it's better to use Python in order to generate this piece of information? The next step would be to break down the aforementioned matrix in weeks.

Thank you in advance

Best regards,
A

Comment: Unless you have used textvalues, date values are merely numeric values which won't change no matter what format you put them in (dd-mm-yy or whichever). Please attach some sample data with expected output and confirm that your data is actually true date values instead of text values that look like dates.

Comment: @JvdV Date values are numeric. The problem is that since both booking and check-in dates are specific, analysis should be focused on month and year. You can find a sample data file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/37inj0zeuzyqmjo/Sample%20data.xlsx?dl=0. What I am trying to do is on Sheet 2.

Comment: In case the above link does not work, try this one: http://www.filedropper.com/sampledata_1

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Don't forget to update your question according to [ask] a question with a [mcve]. That would be beneficial for any future reference. It's not recommended to put relevant information like this in comments.

Comment: @JvdV Thank you very much! Would you recommend creating a table in the post?

Comment: For sure, you can put up some markdown sample data. Is the answer giving you the expected results?

Comment: Yes, thank you once more! It works like a charm. I will try to create a weekly matrix as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result through the following formula in `C3` on Sheet2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)=MONTH($B3))*(YEAR(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)=YEAR($B3))*(MONTH(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10)=MONTH(C$2))*(YEAR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10)=YEAR(C$2)))
```

Drag right and down.

Comment: Would it be possible to convert the SUMPRODUCT formula above into VBA? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @meletkis, yes it is :). I guess we have solved that issue in your other post now haha.